# Найдите пять наименьших значений k, при которых N(k) имеет нечётное количество различных чётных делителей

Tags: python, простые-числа, теория-чисел, факторизация

Пусть N(k) = 1 850 000 000 + k, где k – натуральное число. Найдите пять наименьших значений k, при которых N(k) имеет нечётное количество различных чётных делителей. В ответе запишите найденные значения k в порядке возрастания, справа от каждого значения запишите число чётных делителей N(k).

Правильный ответ:
22792 81,
144450 81,
266112 27,
387778 9,
509448 27.

Мой ответ:
22792 81,
75156 7,
144450 81,
161182 15. - после этого уже остановаливал программу.
Почему выводит какие-то промежуточные числа?

```
from math import sqrt

def f(n):
    counter = 1
    sqrt_n = sqrt(n)
    if sqrt_n.is_integer():
        counter += 1
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt_n)):
        if n % i == 0:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                counter += 1
            if (n // i) % 2 == 0:
                counter += 1
    return counter


N = 1_850_000_000
counter_k = 0
for k in range(2, 1_000_001, 2):
    N_k = f(N + k)
    if N_k % 2 != 0:
        counter_k += 1
        print(k, N_k)
    if counter_k == 5:
        break
```

Comment: ```if sqrt_n.is_integer():
        counter += 1``` проверьте что он чётный...

Comment: @pavel, целый корень четного всегда чётный.

Comment: а где проверка что число чётное? по коду для 9 будет 1 значение, разве нет?

Comment: @pavel, в вызывающем коде перебираются только чётные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1850075156 = 43012 · 43013*

`sqrt_n = 43012.499997093866`

`int(sqrt_n) = 43012`

`range(2, int(sqrt_n)) = [2, 43011]`

В цикле не проверяется делитель *43012*. Ошибка.

### 18 минут

Дифы читать умеете? Вот так можно исправить ваш код. Работать будет 18 минут:

> ```
> $ diff original.py fixed.py
> 7,8c7,8
> <         counter += 1
> <     for i in range(2, int(sqrt_n)):
> ---
> >         counter -= 1
> >     for i in range(2, int(sqrt_n) + 1):
> ```

### 30 секунд

Через разложение на простые задача решается за полминуты. Это лучше чем прямая проверка делителей. И теория за этим красивая, я её повторять не буду, всё есть в ответе Harry. Этот код хорош тем что `factors` - процедура общего назначения, возвращает простые множители числа со степенями, а часть оптимизации спрятана внутри `main` - цикл прерывается как только становится ясно, что число чётных делителей будет чётным:

```
import math


def factors(n):
    i = 2
    j = n
    j_sqrt = math.isqrt(j)
    while i <= j_sqrt:
        if j % i == 0:
            e = 0
            while j % i == 0:
                j //= i
                e += 1
            yield i, e
            j_sqrt = math.isqrt(j)
        i += 1 if i == 2 else 2
    if j > 1:
        yield j, 1


def main():
    m = 0
    k = 0
    while True:
        it = factors(1_850_000_000 + k)
        p, e = next(it)
        assert p == 2
        if e % 2 != 0:
            d = e
            for _, e in it:
                if e % 2 == 1:
                    break
                d *= e + 1
            else:
                print(k, d)
                m += 1
                if m >= 5:
                    break
        k += 2


main()
```

> ```
> $ time python factors.py 
> 22792 81
> 144450 81
> 266112 27
> 387778 9
> 509448 27
>
> real  0m27.966s
> user  0m27.748s
> sys   0m0.008s
> ```

### 1.3 секунды

Сегментированное решето Эратосфена решает задачу быстрее чем за две секунды. Звучит громко, а идея простая - группу соседних чисел можно разложить на множители быстрее, чем если разлагать каждое число в отдельности. Функция `factors(n1, n2)` возвращает простые множители для всех чисел в диапазоне *[n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>)*. В сравнении с разложением одного числа часть оптимизаций теряется. Зато значительно уменьшается число бесполезных проверок делимости:

```
import math


def factors(n1, n2):
    ns = list(range(n1, n2))
    i = 2
    n2_sqrt = math.isqrt(n2)
    while i <= n2_sqrt:
        for k in range((i - n1) % i, n2 - n1, i):
            if ns[k] % i == 0:
                e = 1
                n = ns[k] // i
                while n % i == 0:
                    n //= i
                    e += 1
                ns[k] = n
                yield n1 + k, i, e
        i += 1 if i == 2 else 2
    for n, j in enumerate(ns, start=n1):
        if j > 1:
            yield n, j, 1


def search(n1, n2):
    n_even_divs = [0] * (n2 - n1)
    for n, p, e in factors(n1, n2):
        if p == 2:
            n_even_divs[n - n1] = e
        else:
            n_even_divs[n - n1] *= e + 1
    for n, d in enumerate(n_even_divs, start=n1):
        if d % 2 == 1:
            yield n, d


def main():
    base = 1_850_000_000
    m = 0
    k = base
    step = 25000
    while True:
        for n, d in search(k, k + step):
            print(n - base, d)
            m += 1
            if m >= 5:
                return
        k += step


main()
```

> ```
> $ time python sieve.py 
> 22792 81
> 144450 81
> 266112 27
> 387778 9
> 509448 27
>
> real  0m1.254s
> user  0m1.244s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

### 0.6 секунды

Каждый чётный делитель числа *2n* находится во взаимнооднозначном соответствии с делителем числа *n*. Вместо того чтобы считать чётные делители больших чисел можно считать любые делители в два раза меньших чисел. Это даст двоякий выигрыш: чисел в два раза меньше и сами числа в два раза меньше. Процедура `factors` не меняется. `search` становится проще, `main` - чуть сложнее. Время - 0.6c:

```
def search(n1, n2):
    n_even_divs = [1] * (n2 - n1)
    for n, p, e in factors(n1, n2):
        n_even_divs[n - n1] *= e + 1
    for n, d in enumerate(n_even_divs, start=n1):
        if d % 2 == 1:
            yield n, d


def main():
    base = 1_850_000_000
    m = 0
    k = base // 2
    step = 25000
    while True:
        for n, d in search(k, k + step):
            print(2 * (n - base // 2), d)
            m += 1
            if m >= 5:
                return
        k += step


main()
```

> ```
> $ time python sieve2.py 
> 22792 81
> 144450 81
> 266112 27
> 387778 9
> 509448 27
>
> real  0m0.539s
> user  0m0.524s
> sys   0m0.012s
> ```

### ⅓ секунды

`factors` и `search` можно объединить. Это позволит прекратить вычисления для конкретного числа если стало известно что число делителей будет чётным. Меньше трети секунды:

```
import math


def search(n1, n2):
    sieve = [(1, n) for n in range(n1, n2)]
    i = 2
    n2_sqrt = math.isqrt(n2)
    while i <= n2_sqrt:
        for k in range((i - n1) % i, n2 - n1, i):
            d, n = sieve[k]
            if d != 0 and n % i == 0:
                n //= i
                e = 1
                while n % i == 0:
                    n //= i
                    e += 1
                if e % 2 == 0:
                    sieve[k] = d * (e + 1), n
                else:
                    sieve[k] = 0, 0
        i += 1 if i == 2 else 2
    for n, (d, j) in enumerate(sieve, start=n1):
        if d != 0 and j == 1:
            yield n, d


def main():
    base = 1_850_000_000
    m = 0
    k = base // 2
    step = 25000
    while True:
        for n, d in search(k, k + step):
            print(2 * (n - base // 2), d)
            m += 1
            if m >= 5:
                return
        k += step


main()
```

> ```
> $ time python sieve3.py 
> 22792 81
> 144450 81
> 266112 27
> 387778 9
> 509448 27
>
> real  0m0.312s
> user  0m0.308s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

### ¼ секунды

До сих пор решето прореживалось двойкой и нечётными начиная с трёх. Так как прореживание повторяется вновь и вновь для каждого сегмента, оказывается выгодно построить список простых и использовать его в решете. Со всеми оптимизациями решето надо прореживать делителями до *30418*. Текущая схема сделает *15209* итераций. Схема с простыми делителями - *3285* итераций. Выигрыша в пять раз не будет - удаляются итерации в которых исполняется мало кода. Но какой-то выигрыш получится.

Простые получаются классическим решетом Эратосфена. Выбрать его размер заранее сложно, будем увеличивать решето примерно в два раза, если простых не хватило. Обидно переделывать работу заново, но даже в таком виде решение эффективно. С другой стороны, получится проще чем настоящее сегментированное решето:

```
import math


def primes(n1, n2):
    sieve = bytearray(n2)
    for i in range(2, math.isqrt(n2)):
        if sieve[i] == 0:
            for j in range(i * i, n2, i):
                sieve[j] = 1
    return (i for i in range(max(2, n1), n2) if sieve[i] == 0)


class Primes:
    def __init__(self, start_n=1):
        self._n1 = 0
        self._n2 = max(start_n, 1)
        self._primes = list(primes(self._n1, self._n2))

    def __iter__(self):
        i1 = 0
        while True:
            if i1 >= len(self._primes):
                self._n1 = self._n2
                self._n2 = 2 * self._n2
                self._primes.extend(primes(self._n1, self._n2))
            i2 = len(self._primes)
            yield from (self._primes[j] for j in range(i1, i2))
            i1 = i2


def search(n1, n2, ps):
    sieve = [(1, n) for n in range(n1, n2)]
    n2_sqrt = math.isqrt(n2)
    for i in ps:
        if i >= n2_sqrt:
            break
        for k in range((i - n1) % i, n2 - n1, i):
            d, n = sieve[k]
            if d != 0 and n % i == 0:
                n //= i
                e = 1
                while n % i == 0:
                    n //= i
                    e += 1
                if e % 2 == 0:
                    sieve[k] = d * (e + 1), n
                else:
                    sieve[k] = 0, 0
    for n, (d, j) in enumerate(sieve, start=n1):
        if d != 0 and j == 1:
            yield n, d


def main():
    base = 1_850_000_000
    m = 0
    k = base // 2
    step = 25000
    ps = Primes(25000)
    while True:
        for n, d in search(k, k + step, ps):
            print(2 * (n - base // 2), d)
            m += 1
            if m >= 5:
                return
        k += step


main()
```

> ```
> $ time python sieve4.py 
> 22792 81
> 144450 81
> 266112 27
> 387778 9
> 509448 27
>
> real  0m0.234s
> user  0m0.232s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Comment: Тоесть в цикле функции рэнж идет до int(sqrt(n)) + 1 ?

Comment: Нет. `+ 1` сломает подсчёт делителей для полного квадрата. Но направление мыслей верное.

Comment: Тут дело в скорости, чем быстрее тем лучше

Comment: Тогда нужно округлять с помощью ceil?

Comment: Спасибо! ceil решил вопрос

Comment: Экзаменатор мой код не проверяет, мне нужно получить ответ любыми способами

Comment: С несколькими секундами — разве что потому что на Python :) На С++ быстрее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1496427/195342

Comment: Для понимания при полном непонимании закрученности синтаксиса python... вы выполняете вычисление простых Эратосфеном для каждого поддиапазона? Не однократно один раз для всех разложений? Т.е. по сути оптимизация сводится к тому, что вы вычисляете таблицу простых заново для каждого поддиапазона проверяемых чисел, а не для каждого числа?

Comment: @Harry, понимание правильное. Простых у меня пока нет. Деление на предполагаемый делитель делается сразу для диапазона чисел.

Comment: Просто мне казалось, что для таких чисел, которые вполне укладываются в 32 бита, проще всего вычислить любым способом (я, недолго думая, сделал это перебором) все простые до 65536 однократно.

Comment: @Harry, я этого (пока) не сделал. Код уже сложный. Дополнительный параметр (диапазон простых). Но идея хорошая. Попробую.

Comment: @Harry, сделал простые. Четверть секунды в итоге. И это интерпретатор! Я доволен.

Comment: Тут https://ideone.com/tt1UiE треть :) Что-то я никак не могу продраться через код `search` и понять, как он работает, чтоб на С++ повторить...

Comment: @Harry, 0.014с: https://ideone.com/BhhrmV

Comment: Посидел, поразбирался. Логично — плясать от простых чисел, которых порядка 6000, а не от перебора полумиллиона чисел. В этом варианте и в самом деле деление на 2 имеет смысл.

Comment: Однако поднять скорость в 70000 раз — это что-то особенного :) Даже если только Python — то все равно в 5000 раз — результат впечатляет...

Comment: Решил посмотреть, раз уж для Украины ChapGPT открыли, а что ИИ скажет? Разочаровал: https://i121.fastpic.org/big/2023/0218/88/4cac70e538d4483f9eddb448a9d60c88.jpg

Comment: @Harry, что может сделать робот с материалом чего не можете вы или я? Он точно так же компилирует известные факты во что-то напоминающее решение. Фаза проверки отсутствует. Если вы чего-то не знали, он, возможно, вам это сообщит. Но в целом это будет какой-то средний уровень. Я только за последние две недели нарыл уйму нового материала по проверке простоты, разложениям, решетам. Когда у робота дойдут до этого руки?

Comment: @Harry, сам факт внушает уважение. Ещё один шаг к сильному ИИ. Но пока не сам сильный ИИ.

Comment: К сожалению, наличие сильного ИИ будет убивать ЕИ... Реальный случай — водитель вогнался в озеро потому что навигатор ему сказал ехать прямо. Смешно? скорее страшно... Впрочем, это тема в лучшем случае для меты.

Answer (score 3):

Простите, но я уж на своем родном языке :)

Заинтересовал ответ Stanislav Volodarskiy - ведь полная факторизация не всегда нужна, если степень нечетного простого делителя четная - уже все понятно :)

Чуток математики: число должно иметь вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где *p<sub>i</sub>* - нечетные простые.

При этом общее количество *четных* делителей (включая само это число, которое, как выяснилось, входит в количество делителей) равно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и должно быть нечетным. Что возможно только в том случае, когда ***все*** сомножители нечетны.

Так что даже перебор

```
unsigned int odd_evenEn(unsigned int N)
{
    unsigned int count = 1;
    if (N%2) return false;
    unsigned int k = 0;
    while(N%2 == 0) { N/=2; ++k; }
    if (k%2 == 0) return 0;
    for(unsigned int p = 3; p*p <= N; p+=2)
    {
        if (N%p) continue;
        unsigned int k = 0;
        while(N%p == 0) { N /= p; ++k; }
        if (k%2) return 0;
        count *= 1+k;
    }
    if (N > 1) return 0;
    return count*k;
}
```

дает неплохие результаты, а уж если сначала табличку простых составить и по ней работать - и того быстрее.

Полный код с замером времени в обоих вариантах - тут: https://ideone.com/F2clOy

Для чистоты эксперимента построение таблицы простых тоже замерялось.

Было бы интересно перевести это на Python и замерить...

Comment: По соседству добавил решение на Питоне. Две секунды - не плохо для интерпретатора.

Comment: Питон укладывается в треть секунды.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy https://ideone.com/ddzqrQ - вполне разумная разница между 0.29 на С++ (правда, без сегментированного решета) и 0.42 на Python

Answer (score 0):

Дополню, что даже с вашим кодом (исправленным) если добавить `numba.njit`, то будет считать меньше чем за минуту. Иногда полезно так тоже уметь. Показан только кусок с исправлениями:

```py
from numba import njit # импортируем ускоритель

@njit # ускоряющий декоратор
def f(n):
    counter = 1
    sqrt_n = sqrt(n)
    if int(sqrt_n) == sqrt_n: # с numba не работает is_integer
        counter += 1
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt_n) + 1): # про это исправление уже писали
```

Comment: Использовать можно только стандартные библиотеки python

Comment: Понятно. Но когда вы тестируете код и вам хочется просто побыстрее проверить результат, который выдаёт код, вам же никто не может запретить использовать что-то для ускорения? )

Comment: Спасибо за совет!